# SIPS Image Manipulation

Tags: bash, terminal, find, exec, sips

I am trying to use the following command to find all PDFs in the current directory (not recursively) - however I don't think it likes the '{}' on the --out.

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 -exec sips -s format jpeg --resampleHeightWidth 129 100 '{}' --out '{}'.jpg \;
```

The find work when used with -print and sips works when I specify the name --out test.jpg.  Any way to make this work? Or should I try xargs? I don't really want to use a loop for simplicity... Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I attempted using xargs - but again get an error out_dir_not_found.

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I % sips -s format jpeg --resampleHeightWidth 129 100 % --out "%.jpg"


mymbpro:pdfs dh$ find . -iname "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I % sips -s format jpeg --resampleHeightWidth 129 100 % --out "%.jpg"
Error 10: out_dir_not_found /Users/darenhunter/Desktop/pdfs/ATTENTION.pdf.jpg
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
Error 10: out_dir_not_found /Users/darenhunter/Desktop/pdfs/DisNCLB119.pdf.jpg
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
Error 10: out_dir_not_found /Users/darenhunter/Desktop/pdfs/services2012.pdf.jpg
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
Error 10: out_dir_not_found /Users/darenhunter/Desktop/pdfs/Fall2011.pdf.jpg
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
```

Comment: Try your original find command, but with an echo:  `-exec echo sips ...`. Do the commands it outputs work when you run them at a prompt? Does it ask for any information?

Answer (score 2):

> If you will be executing over many results, it is more efficient to pipe the
>   results to the `xargs` command instead. `xargs` is a more modern
>   implementation, and handles long lists in a more intelligent way. The
>   `print0` option can be used with this.
>
> The following command will ensure that filenames with whitespaces are passed
>   to the executed COMMAND without being split up by the shell. It looks
>   complicated at first glance, but is widely used.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 COMMAND
```

[**ref**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Find)

Comment: Nope - just terminal on OS X.

Comment: how do I refer to the file name within the COMMAND?